# Hiding, displaying and focusing editText's in Android

Tags: java, android

I've two linked questions.

I'm applying a slide translation on an editText and it's button. I've created two buttons, one visible and one invisible, for obvious reasons. In order to hide the one that was visible and show the one that was invisiable I'm using this code:

```
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    textBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    textBox2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    textBox2.requestFocus();
    button2.setEnabled(true);
    button.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Where `textBox` is the original editText and `button` is its accompanying button. `textBox2` is the one I want to show.

Yet the original editText and its button remain visible and the other set don't appear. Any ideas whats wrong with above?

Second, I can find screen size in my .java file, but how could I pass this into my .xml animation file? Or is there a better way of adjusting the amount of transition depending on the screen size?

Here's how I invoke the animation:

```
Animation translateAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(first.this, R.anim.translate);
textBox.startAnimation(translateAnimation);
```

Translate.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:fillAfter="true" android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="-160" android:duration="50" />
```

Comment: ur visible/invisible code looking fine. My doubt is both sets r same so even if its working fine, it seems like wrong. Is thr any differentiating factor among those 2 editText n button sets like different name etc?

Comment: please post ur xml file containing editText n buttons

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first part of your question you would probably want to call invalidate() on the views for which you have changed the visibility.
For the second part it might be better if you could show how are you adjusting the transition in your code currently.

Comment: I think its better that you put all your animation code into the java file itself rather than doing it from xml. That ways you will not have to harcode the values.
`code`
Animation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(fromXDelta, toXDelta, fromYDelta, toYDelta);
        translateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        translateAnimation.setDuration(50);
`code`